# Semi-Circulo con CSS

Tags: html, css

Estoy intentando dibujar la siguiente imagen con CSS, he probado de varias formas con border-radius, sin ningún éxito. Existe alguna forma sencilla de implementarlo? [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí].

Comment: CSS Interpreta todos los elementos del DOM como un rectángulo o un cuadrado. Por la forma en la que está la curba sería imposible de realizar.

Comment: Puedes intentarlo hacer con https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/

Comment: Esto se podría realizar de diferentes maneras: con pseudo-elementos, con `radial-gradient`, con SVG... indica qué es lo que has intentado y con qué problemas o dificultades te estás encontrando.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No es la opción más elegante y tienes que calcular manualmente donde posicionar los elementos... Pero es una que utiliza conceptos sencillos, puedes usar un rectángulo y un circulo para crear el mismo efecto, así:

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}

#test {
  background-color: red;
  height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#test:after {
  content: "";
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 800px;
  width: 800px;
  position: absolute;
  left: -300px;
  top: -770px;
}
```

```html
<div id='test' />
```